# Python : How I can draw FFT graph with Pandas DataFrame which is made by time and values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, fft

I am trying to make FFT graph which is derived from Pandas DataFrame.

It is my source code I tried with.

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
from scipy.fft import fftfreq 
plt.style.use("seaborn")

data = pd.read_csv("/Users/kyungyunlee/Desktop/ IRP reference/Data/PIXEL_DATA/1_piece.csv")

N = len(t)
t = data["time"].loc[data["time"] > 5].loc[data["time"] < 10]
s = data["y_value"].loc[data["time"] > 5].loc[data["time"] < 10]
print(len(s))

fft = np.fft.fft(s)
fftfreq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(s))

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.xlabel("Frquency Domain")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.plot(fftfreq, fft)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.show()
```

And the picture below is the result of the source code.
As you can see from the graph, the left graph is FFT and the right graph is the time and amplitude graph. In this situation, I can't understand why my FFT graph is like that. The graph is weird but I can't find what the problem is.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBCGD.png)

Please check this Pandas dataframe screenshot. very simple data consist with time(maybe ms) and values.

```
time,y_value
5.009026,614
5.035417,550
5.061302,554
5.08712,611
5.114184,613
5.140525,614
5.167711,573
5.19439,532
5.220309,596
5.247532,607
5.273929,608
5.300062,588
5.326553,529
5.352314,577
5.378559,602
5.404629,602
5.431329,597
5.459119,547
5.486477,556
5.512459,597
5.539668,594
5.567103,597
5.594013,564
5.621206,539
5.646212,586
5.671964,594
5.698939,594
5.726222,577
5.777665,574
5.804736,590
5.831811,590
5.858152,583
5.885826,543
5.912285,562
5.937549,587
5.991617,585
6.018168,555
6.044418,547
6.07098,581
6.097121,585
6.124821,585
6.151159,566
6.177994,536
6.205361,573
6.232069,582
6.25743,582
6.284097,573
6.31036,537
6.336849,564
6.363457,580
6.390022,580
6.417727,576
6.444151,549
6.471022,553
6.498445,576
6.551982,577
6.578571,557
6.60393,544
6.631363,571
6.657855,576
6.685089,576
6.711603,563
6.763428,565
6.789426,574
6.815717,574
6.841412,569
6.867886,543
6.867886,517
6.89452,558
6.921834,572
6.974582,570
7.00143,550
7.029219,550
7.055249,569
7.109767,570
7.137385,556
7.188917,565
7.215901,569
7.215901,543
7.243045,569
7.270299,561
7.32553,560
```

What I want to do is to draw FFT graph with this Data but I don't know why the code is not working.

I hope I can get some feedbacks. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think that's wrong?  The DC component is by far the most significant contributor.  The DC level is about 530, and none of the other peaks is larger than about 100.  If you don't want the DC, take the average of your Y values and subtract it from the Ys.

Comment: Or, to cheat, set `fft[0] = 0` after the FFT call.

Comment: @TimRoberts Firstly, thank you for your good answer, Tim. Why I thought the graph is weird was that the graph is a little bit different that I have watched. And in my opinion, my expected frequency is 10hz but, the frequency on the graph is too small, 0.0066. So, I am confused. T

Comment: `fftfreq` doesn't know your time values.  It assumes the entire array is one second, and returns values from -0.5 to +0.5.  If you adjust the scale using `np.fft.fftfreq(len(s)) * (len(s)/(t.max() - t.min()))`, then the peak is about 7.2Hz, which looks right.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for your feedback Tim. Um, actually I got the same graph with your new feedback but I need to try myself more! Even if I changed the fftfreq, the graph looks the same and the frequency domain changed from -20 to 20.

Comment: Right.  It won't change the shape of the graph, it just changes the X axis.  That's all that `fftfreq` is used for -- generating the X axis.  See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you suppress the DC node and adjust the axes, the results seem pretty reasonable:

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
from scipy.fft import fftfreq 
plt.style.use("seaborn")

data = pd.read_csv("x.data")
print(data)

t = data["time"].loc[data["time"] > 5].loc[data["time"] < 10]
s = data["y_value"].loc[data["time"] > 5].loc[data["time"] < 10]

fft = np.fft.fft(s)
fft[0] = 0
fftfreq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(s))*len(s)/(t.max()-t.min())

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.xlabel("Frquency Domain")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.plot(fftfreq, fft)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

And if you plot the power spectrum (np.abs(fft)), you get:
[image]